# larget/smallest number in a range in excel without overlap

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a sheet with 1000 rows and 5 columns.
1) What I want to do is in a cloumn find the biggest number in 5 adjacent row (e.g. row 1-5 in column A). then find the biggest number in next 5 rows (i.e. 6-10 in columnA), then find the biggest three in next 5 rows (i.e. 11-15 in cloumn A) and so on till row 1000 is reached.

2)Smallest in 5 adjacent rows(row 1-5 in ColumnB), then the smallest in in next 5 rows (6-10 in Column B) and so on.

3) in Column C i want only every 5  value to be selected (i.e. every 5th item)

Comment: What? I don't understand. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ok let me give an example. I have data for stocks for every min in open high low close format.

Comment: Ok let me give an example. I have data for stocks for every min in open/high/low/close format. now how can i covert it into 5 minute format meaning for 1-5 minutes what is the open (the first data in column of open), highest (from the column of high) and lowest (from column of lowest) and close(the last data in column of close). after this move to next 5 minutes (from 6 -10 min) and find out the same. when I apply LARGE it do the calculations for minutes 1-5 then 2-6 then 3-7 instead i want for minutes 1-5 then 6-10 then 11-15. is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference 5 rows at a time you could use the offset function where you can specify a row offset and a height.  Put the following formula in row 1.

```
=sum(offset($A$1,(row(A1)-1)*5,0,5))
```

This would sum cells A1:A5.  If it is copied down to row 2 it would sum A6:10 and so forth.

The offset function could also be used inside a min, max, large function.  The -1 and $a$1 will need to be adjusted if you are using headers or starting in any row except 1.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to get the formulas you want in the first 5 rows.  Then copy them, select all 1000 rows and then paste.  The formulas will then be pasted in blocks of 5 all the way to the bottom.

Comment: first 5 rows meaning from 1 min to 5 min?

Comment: All of the formulas for the first 5 rows in each column where you want formulas.

Comment: I am sorry but its not working the way I want it to be. All i need is a stock data in 1 min O/H/L/C format be converted into 5 min O/H/L/C format. the way you suggested is not producing this effect i am sorry

Comment: What did you do, exactly?  Did you fill down or copy and paste as I suggested?

Comment: I first tried to create the 2 min chart from 1 min chart. so i first made two rows with the formula. tried to fill it down.it didn't work then copy it down it didnot work. then i filled 5 rows with the 2 min formula then copied filled it down and then copied it down. none of this worked.

Comment: I said to get the first 5 rows or formulas as you want them and then copy down.  You won't be able to do it from 1 or 2 rows.

Comment: yes sir. I filled the 2 min formulas in first 5 rows and only then i tried to copy the block of this first 5 to other rows.. its not giving that result

Comment: I would have to see the exact formula that you're using.

Comment: how can i send it to you? if you can send me your email. i will send it to you with my query as well

Comment: Post your workbook on Dropbox and post a link here.